# In windows XP SP3, repair console is not showing

Tags: windows-xp, windows-installation

When I insert the CD and I want to repair my PC, there is no option for repairing:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

It looks like your file table is gone. The Windows installer doesn't recognize the old partition as a valid NTFS or FAT32 filesystem, so there is no Windows installation to repair. You cannot repair this from the Windows XP install CD.

Comment: What makes you think that.  There are other commands he could try "fixmbr" for instance and the command to fix the MFT.

Comment: @Ramhound, as far as I can remember, you'd have get into the Repair Console to do so. OP states he doesn't get that far and I can't remember if it was this screen that provided that option, or one earlier. No Repair Console means no way to start `fdisk /fixmbr` or `fdisk /fixboot`. He might try a bootfloppy, but again, I can't remember the details so I did not provide those as solution. No repair console means he cannot fix it with this CD, there may be other solutions.